# Can you make valid Makefiles without tab characters?

Tags: makefile, tabs, whitespace, spaces

```
target: dependencies
    command1
    command2
```

On my system (Mac OS X), `make` seems to require that that Makefiles have a tab character preceding the the content of each `command` line, or it throws a syntax error.

This is an annoyance when creating or editing Makefiles because I have my editor set up to be all-spaces-all-the-time.

Can you make valid Makefiles without tab characters?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This is a syntax oddity/requirement of `make`, it has nothing to do with Mac OS X.  Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about it if you are going to use `make`.

*Edit*: GNU Make now supports a custom recipe prefix.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21920142).

You are not the first one to dislike this aspect of `make`. To quote [Unix Haters' Handbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_UNIX-HATERS_Handbook):

> The problem with Dennis’s Makefile is that when he added the comment line, he inadvertently inserted a space before the tab character at the beginning of line 2. The tab character is a very important part of the syntax of Makefiles. All command lines (the lines beginning with cc in our example) must start with tabs. After he made his change, line 2 didn’t, hence the error.
>
> “So what?” you ask, “What’s wrong with that?”
>
> There is nothing wrong with it, by itself. It’s just that when you consider how other programming tools work in Unix, using tabs as part of the syntax is like one of those pungee stick traps in The Green Berets: the poor kid from Kansas is walking point in front of John Wayne and doesn’t see the trip wire. After all, there are no trip wires to watch out for in Kansas corn fields. WHAM!

Comment: The issue with tabs is one of the first thing anyone using make learns - I've never found it to be a real problem.

Comment: @Neil, Me neither: I never said I agreed with the UHH, I was just saying some people don't like it. :-)

Comment: Seems like a good plug for using cmake. Not the only frustrating oddity in make syntax.

Comment: I just found https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html (see `.RECIPEPREFIX`).  One of the answers below also mentions that, and should be marked as "correct" instead of mine.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21920142

Comment: It's not a huge problem, but it is annoying. Each and every time. It is reliably annoying, and it is annoying in \omicron linear time.

Comment: Funny remark about make and tabs in the first point of this [article](https://kukuruku.co/post/the-collapse-of-the-unix-philosophy/) :)  "He did it this way, as he didn’t think that ```make``` would be used by anyone except for this small group of people. Later came the idea that ```make``` was a good thing and it would be nice to include it into the standard UNIX package. _In order not to break the already written makefiles, (meaning written by these ten people), he decided not to change anything._ Well, that’s how it goes… We all suffer because of those ten guys."

Answer (score 69):

In the time since this question was originally asked, a version of GNU Make has been released that allows you to use something other than <kbd>Tab</kbd> as the prefix character. [From the mailing list announcement](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/make-alpha/2010-07/msg00025.html):

> New special variable: .RECIPEPREFIX allows you to reset the recipe
>   introduction character from the default (TAB) to something else.  The
>   first character of this variable value is the new recipe introduction
>   character.  If the variable is set to the empty string, TAB is used again.
>   It can be set and reset at will; recipes will use the value active when
>   they were first parsed.  To detect this feature check the value of $(.RECIPEPREFIX).

This feature was added in GNU Make 3.82, released in July 2010 (six months after this question's original ask date). Since it has in turn been three years and change since that, it's likely that other Make flavors have followed GNU Make.

Comment: aaaand my up-to-date Mac OSX still uses version 3.81 from 2006. Totally unexpected.

Comment: aaaand my up-to-date Mac OSX still uses version 3.81 from 2006. In 2021. You can update this with Homebrew but still.

Comment: Apple still uses GNU make?  Seems they haven't found a suitable replacement yet…

Answer (score 56):

There is a convoluted way of have a valid makefile without tabs.

If you change your makefile to read:

```
target: dependencies; command1; command2
```

If will work.  If you want it on more than one line, then you can do:

```
target: dependencies; \
command1; \
command2
```

Messy, but it works.

Comment: Upgrading to a version of Make that supports `.RECIPEPREFIX` is probably the best approach.  However, since I didn't feel like doing that, I ended up using a solution based on this one.  Line 1: `target:\ ` , Line 2: [four-space indentation] followed by `;command`

Answer (score 37):

If you have a vimrc in your profile you can add this line to prevent vim from changing  to spaces:

```
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab
```

I too was struggling with this, and this fixed it for me. Spread the good word!

Answer (score 22):

Try (note the space at the end):

`.RECIPEPREFIX +=`

Comment: What version of make supports this? This doesn't work in GNU Make 4.1.

Comment: GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu i'm sorry but it does work

Comment: probably, it needs to mentioned, that this variable needs to be declared inside make file itself (prefixing dot easy not to spot)

Comment: At least in version 4.2, this should work. [The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) says in the explanation of `.RECIPEPREFIX` that "If the variable is empty (as **it is by default**) that character is the standard tab character." This means the variable is defined by default. It is confirmed by using `ifeq ($(origin .RECIPEPREFIX), undefined)`. Because `+=` append **a single space** and the rhs to the lhs, `var +=` sets `var` to a single space (plus an empty string) as long as `var` has already be defined. (If `var` isn't defined, `+=` is the same as `=`.)

Comment: If `.RECIPEPREFIX` isn't defined by default (though I don't know whether actually there is such a version of GNU Make), you can write `.RECIPEPREFIX =` right before `.RECIPEPREFIX +=`. The first definition create the variable (this is the important part) and set its value to null. Another technique to set any variable to whitespace(s) is explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors).

Comment: This answer no longer works. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60363121/8776746) for the latest solution.

Comment: link is broken :(

Answer (score 15):

If you are using [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/), you can add the following lines to your `.editorconfig` file to force your IDE to use tab for indentation instead of spaces in `Makefile`:

```
[Makefile]
indent_style = tab
```

Answer (score 14):

In vim's insert mode, one can use `Ctrl-v <TAB>` to insert a literal tab, even if you have set the tab key to insert spaces. This doesn't answer your question, of course, but might be an alternative to the methods available to avoid needing literal tabs.

Comment: This works for me... Awesome, after many years :)

Answer (score 13):

**Until GNU Make 4.2**

[Steven Penny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26200436/8776746) works.

```
.RECIPEPREFIX +=
```

The reason why this works is described in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131213/can-you-make-valid-makefiles-without-tab-characters/26200436#comment103711063_26200436).

---

**Since GNU Make 4.3** (released on 19 Jan 2020)

Behavior of `+=` operator has been [changed](https://lwn.net/Articles/810071/) in a backward-incompatible way. If the left operand has an empty value, a space is **no longer** added.

You can instead use

```
.RECIPEPREFIX := $(.RECIPEPREFIX)<space>
```

, where `<space>` is a single space. Although `$(.RECIPEPREFIX)` is expanded as an empty value, this is needed not to let GNU Make ignore `<space>`. Note this code works even on GNU Make older than version 4.3.

<sub>(For an essentially same but more readable solution, see [@milahu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131213/can-you-make-valid-makefiles-without-tab-characters/60363121?noredirect=1#comment133331794_60363121).)</sub>

Comment: This is kinda crazy, given the above-mentioned fact that tabs were originally used to preserve backwards compatibility for 10 people!

Comment: Thx! Now I can use `gmake`(version 4.4) with `spaces` on my Mac!

Comment: see also [Special Characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html#Special-Characters) to define a `space` variable

Comment: trailing whitespace is bad. the shortest solution is `.RECIPEPREFIX := $() #`. the most popular solution on [github](https://github.com/search?q=RECIPEPREFIX+filename%3Amakefile) is `.RECIPEPREFIX := $(.RECIPEPREFIX) $(.RECIPEPREFIX)`

Answer (score 2):

in ubuntu: vi Makefiles
replace space by tab (or anything else you want):

```
:%s/<space chars>/^I/g
```

For ex replace 8 spaces by tab:

```
:%s/        /^I/g
```

Be attention: **^I** insert with tab key, not **^** and **I** characters :D

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to cause make to use spaces instead of tabs is:

```
.RECIPEPREFIX := $() $()
```

- Makes no assumption about the previous value of .RECIPEPREFIX.
- Requires no space at end of line.
- Easy for a beginner to understand.

Answer (score -6):

Not portably. Certain flavours of make absolutely require tab characters. Yet another reason for preferring tabs over spaces :-)