# To set a preference value to makefile editor

Tags: java, makefile, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse we have the option `Window->Preferences->Editors->Text Editors->Insert spaces for tabs` to convert tab into spaces, but this is not applicable for `makefile`s.

To implement this for `makefile`s I am also trying to use `InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode()`. Is this the correct way? If yes, what should I pass as argument for `getnode()`? If no, please guide with correct way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'implement this for makefile'? Are you writing a new text editor? Please explain in much more detail what you are trying to write.

Comment: Window->Preferences->Editors->Text Editors->Insert spaces for tabs ,after setting this option true,if i press any .txt file ,instead of tab i will get spaces according to the tab spaces we gave.but in makefile ,if i press tab it works like tab only.i want ,if i press tab in makefile ,i have to get spaces instead of tab.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what has `InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode()` got to do with this? What are you trying to do to fix this?

Comment: i thought,By passing makefile editor's plugin id as an argument to getNode() we can set the preference.I am not sure about this.Please correct me ,if i am wrong.

Comment: Only if the editor is written to look for that preference.

Comment: In any case in makefiles tabs are required - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2131213/2670892

Comment: yes.InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode(EditorsUI.PLUGIN_ID).putBoolean().i have passed MakeUIPlugin.getPluginId() to getNode and preference value to putBoolean .but it is not working. makefile means a file with .mak extension .

Comment: That doesn't do anything that the Preferences setting isn't already doing. As I said tabs are **required** in makefiles so to the editor is probably deliberately not using this setting.

Comment: so ,are you  telling it is not possible to do this for .mak file?